# Injective holomorphic functions with non-zero derivative on the closed unit disk implies injectivity on its neighborhood.

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an exercise in the book "Function Theory of One Complex Variable" by Greene and Krantz (Chpater 3, problem 62) and stated as the following:

> Let $f$ be holomorphic on a neighborhood of $\overline{D}(0,1)$. Assume that the restriction of $f$ to $\overline{D}(0,1)$ is one-to-one and $f'$ is nowhere zero on $\overline{D}(0,1)$. Prove that in fact $f$ is one-to-one on a neighborhood of $\overline{D}(0,1)$.

I try to use the inverse function theorem to reach contradictions. Here is what I tried: assume that $f$ is not injective on any neighborhood of $D(0,1)$. Then we construct two sequences $\{z_n\},\{w_n\}$ such that we take $z_n,w_n\in D(0,1+\epsilon/n)$ s.t. $f(z_n)=f(w_n)$. If $z_n,w_n$ finally come to a ball around $p$ on the boundary of the unit disk, then I can conclude the contradiction using inverse function theorem. However, it is guaranteed. Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: the idea is sound; choose a convergent sub-sequence of $z_n$ and by renaming we can assume it is $z_n$ and then same with $w_n$ (from the indices in the sub-sequence of $z_n$) so $z_n \to z, w_n \to w$; clearly $f(z)=f(w), |z|=|w|=1$ so by hypothesis we have $z=w$ and then use that $f'(z) \ne 0$ to get the required contradiction

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!